# Search query to match all and return all data without using curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with postman and i want to try using getting all data from my index, now when using curl

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

but i want to write a search and return all data, my index name is tourdata and type is tours

```
127.0.0.1:9200/tourdata/tours/_search
```

how do i continue

Answer (score 1):

So i found that i need to add size to my query parameter, This worked for me.

```
127.0.0.1:9200/tourdata/tours/_search?size=7000&pretty=true
```

Comment: For larger data sets you'd want to use Scroll API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html